# generate documentation with relative paths

Tags: haskell, documentation

I am trying to setup cabal config such that it can generate documentation in a form that I can browse it locally or remotely. So one of the requirement is to generate a correct form of html, i.e. a relative path.

I've searched around but it seems there are too many combinations of options so I think it's better to ask over here and see if anybody knows.

my current config:

```
documentation: True
```

other options are irrelevant. and compiler generate links similar to this one:

```
file:///home/hu/.cabal/share/doc/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3/lens-4.14/html/Control-Lens.html
```

this makes me only able to read the doc locally. so I would expect in html, it contains the link as:

```
lens-4.14/html/Control-Lens.html
```

such that in a remote browser, i can see the link as:

```
http://linux/ghc-doc/lens-4.14/html/Control-Lens.html
```

hope that makes sense.

anyone knows what options i need to set to enable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really find a solution so i ended up writing my own cgi script that will help me do the transformation. here is the gist:

https://gist.github.com/HuStmpHrrr/b7de3c49f77a925dc6cf85da16a1d231

where `pipeline` is the one that will correct the hyperlinks. since it's a quick and dirty scripting, it will be appreciated if one can point out what i can improve from this.

also we will need to setup the http server(in my case, it's apache2):

1. enable cgi

   LoadModule cgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_cgi.so
2. config your apache to run cgi:

   ```
    ScriptAlias /cgis/ $somepath/cgis/
    <Directory "$somepath/cgis">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
   ```
3. and place the cgi file over there. it should be able to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [`stack`](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) -- it creates HTML docs with relative links like you want.

For each package, just run:

```
stack build --haddock <package-name>
```

or

```
stack --resolver ... build --haddock <package-name>
```

to use a specific resolver. Then look in `$HOME/.stack/snapshots/<arch>/<resolver>/<ghc-version>/doc/`

Note - `<package-name>` is just the package name - not including the version.

The caveat is that stack won't rebuild packages - maybe there's a flag for that - but you can always expunge your snapshots directory before starting.

Comment: will this one generate a centralized index.html page?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want this: http://documentup.com/feuerbach/standalone-haddock

Quote: It generates documentation ... with proper links:

- links to identifiers inside this package set are relative
- links to identifiers from external packages lead to hackage

Comment: one of my concern is the centralized `index.html` page. that would be very helpful. i haven't used this tool. will it maintain this index file?